# Optimizing search speeds for finding specific substrings _in specific positions_ in a single column

Tags: mysql

I have a table that has, among its primary keys, a VARCHAR(16) column that always contains 16 characters.  I'm currently searching for various substrings *at specific positions* within this column using "LIKE CONCAT('_______________', ?)", "LIKE CONCAT('______________', ? '_')", etc to use a 1 char example, but it is not necessarily always one char.  The char varies with each parameter ? and through each query I do, and there are often many of these LIKEs ORed together.  While automatically generating that query is no big deal, it still isn't fast enough.  I was considering splitting the column into 16 VARCHAR(1) columns and doing = ? queries, as they appear to go much faster for simple tests, but this is getting ridiculous.

Is there any way to make mysql index a certain string column by every character in it?  Because that is basically what I need.  Or is the best way to do it separating it all up into 1 char fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to make mysql index a certain string column by every character in it?

Some databases support functional indexes which would allow you to do this. Unfortunately MySQL isn't one of them.

> Or is the best way to do it separating it all up into 1 char fields?

I'd go with this. You may also want to consider denormalizing and storing *both* representations if you also want to be able to perform a lookup on the entire key.

Comment: Ok, well, splitting that text column into 16 char columns means I can't use my previous primary key setup, since I had 2 other columns included and mysql is capped at 16.  I put my last 2 columns I was using before as the primary key and made a separate index on the 16 char columns.  However, now I'm thinking that's a bad idea.  Should I just leave the last 2 columns out of primary keying/indexing altogether?  Note that all "3" (more like 18 now) are required for me to have a unique row.  I need to find unique rows with an insert or update on duplicate, but otherwise only use the 16 chars...